# Transpose in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have the input as mentioned below and output as mentioned below. May I know if any one has written transpose in hive.

**Input:**

```
id  street  seqnbr
100 nj  1
100 ca  2
100 ny  3
100 va  4
```

As per the sequence number , the street will go to st1, st2 respectively.

**Output:**

```
id     st1  st2 st3 st4
100    nj   ca  ny  va
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to transpose data in Hive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624991/is-there-a-way-to-transpose-data-in-hive)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pivot a multiple rows into one row with multiple columns (like reshape cast in R)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920309/pivot-a-multiple-rows-into-one-row-with-multiple-columns-like-reshape-cast-in-r)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transpose/pivot data in hive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025380/how-to-transpose-pivot-data-in-hive)